# Get .Net XML documentation to return specific type for Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-comments

I have a method like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a typed Dictionary of <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"/> 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary()
```

When I invoke this method and look at the intellisense it shows it return `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

Is there a way for the intellisense to show `Dictionary<string, object>`

I tried the below but that fails:

```
<see cref="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"/>
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

Comment: But it does show `Dictionary<string, object>` in the popup, as you wanted?

Comment: yeah, its just the comment bit in the intellisense where it shows Dictionary<TKey,TValue>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a typed Dictionary of <see cref="Dictionary{String, Object}" />
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary()
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: But what exactly did you want to see? I thought you needed exact types in the popup - they're there now.

Comment: They are thanks but I get curly braces not angle brackets, maybe its a limitation

Comment: I'm guessing they want the <string,object> instead of the {string,object}. However, the documentation of the cref attributes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx) states that { and } are to be used. The generated XML file looks correct, so I think this might actually be the way to go. Of course, if you want Sandcastle and similar to generate it with custom text, you can set the custom text as contents of the see-element. VS will ignore the content, however.

Answer (score -1):

You 'could' declare the types at generic class level

```
public Dictionary<T, T2> ToDictionary()
```

Then use documentation such as

```
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of xxxx</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T2">The type of xxxx</typeparam>
```

Just a thought...

DC

Comment: The class this is in is a Dynamic Dictionary so I can't specify the types when the class is constructed.